# Get specific key from returned array directly?

Tags: php, arrays, return-value

```
$user_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)['user_id'];
```

Is something like this possible in PHP?
If so, in which version was it added?

Comment: Okay, are there handy alternatives for 5.3?

Comment: i guess you can use current(array_column($sqlResult,'user_id')); as well but i wouldn't advise it if you don't want your code to get messy ;o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.4 onwards support this kind of operation.

For previous versions you could use [`extract`](http://php.net/extract)

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($someQuery);
extract($data);
```

You would need to ensure you aren't overwriting existing variables using this.

Or you could of course just grab the index you want.

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($someQuery);
$user_id = $data['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [`list()`](http://php.net/list) construct with [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-row):

```
list($a, $b, $c) = mysql_fetch_row($someQuery);
```

---

**NOTE:** [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

For `mysqli` I suggest to note [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) function.

Comment: I'm well aware that `mysql_` is deprecated. Thank you.